# When I try to create screen navigation in react native, my expo screen shows a blank screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create screen navigation between screens in my react native website, but when I try to do this it shows a blank screen on my expo screen. I'm not sure what the problem is, can somebody please look at my code for me. My App.js is:

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import HomeScreen from './screens/Home'
import LoginScreen from './screens/login'

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const MyStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Home' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="login" component={LoginScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default MyStack
```

My Home Screen code is:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const home = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('login')} title='Next Screen'/>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default home
```

Comment: did you implement the login screen and how do you import component in your App.js

Comment: I added the login screen but it still doesn't work

Comment: How do you import components in app.js file

Comment: Where is the `navigation` object coming from in `home`?

Comment: @mirsahib I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @DavidScholz what do you mean?

Comment: In the posted code, the `onPress` function in the `home` component uses a navigation object in order to navigate. This object is never defined.

Comment: @DavidScholz so what do I do?

Comment: I am just pointing out a mistake in the code that you have posted. If you really use the above code in your current project, then this will throw an error since navigation is not defined. Either the posted code does not match the one in your setup or you have posted the wrong code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two mistakes I spotted in HomeScreen

1. `navigation` is not defined

```
const home = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
```

2. `Button` is not imported

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
```

The rest look fine, and I even put it on a snack and tested it

https://snack.expo.dev/@mohammed-handa/simple-stack

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const LoginScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Login Screen</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
};
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('login')}
        title="Next Screen"
      />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
};

const MyStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Home' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="login" component={LoginScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
export default MyStack;
```

Comment: Should I add this code to my app.js or are they meant to be separated into their respective files?